# How to inject another service to specific test case in angular testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

As in the above title question - is it possible to inject another instance of a service into specific test function? I mean situation, where in test suit I inject some service in beforeEach method.

Creating a stub:

```
let userServiceStub = {
  hasReadPermissions() { return true; },
  isUserInformationAvailable() { return true; },
  isUserRequestForbidden() { return true; }
};
```

In beforeEach method configuring test module:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    SomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceStub },
              { provide: AnotherService, useValue: anotherServiceStub }],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
}).compileComponents();
```

Then I have to test cases:

First where I would like to use service stub injected in TestBed

```
it('should render topbar when user has read permissions', () => {
  let topbar = debugElement.query(By.css('topbar'));
  expect(topbar).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Second where I want to use another stub of the same service:

```
let anotherUserServiceStub = {
  hasReadPermissions() { return false; },
  isUserInformationAvailable() { return false; },
  isUserRequestForbidden() { return true; }
};

it('should render appropriate message when user has not read permissions', 
   inject([UserService], (userService: UserService) => { <--- how to inject another user service stub here?
       let message = debugElement.query(By.css('h2'));
       expect(message).toBe('you have no permissions');
   }));
```

Or perhaps I'm trying to do it inappropriate way at all? Please point me a right way.

[[EDIT]]

Part of component logic:

```
dataUnavailable: boolean = false;
noPermissions: boolean = false;

constructor(private toastr: ToastsManager, 
          vRef: ViewContainerRef,
          private userService: UserService,
          private router: Router) {
  this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vRef);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  if (!this.isUserInformationAvailable()) {
    if (this.isUserRequestForbidden()) {
      this.noPermissions = true;
    } else {
      this.dataUnavailable = true;
      this.toastr.error("An error occured while getting data from server.");
    }
  }
}

hasUserReadPermissions(): boolean {
  return this.userService.hasReadPermissions();
}
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hasUserReadPermissions()">
  <topbar></topbar>
  <main-menu></main-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-container>
<div class="row" *ngIf="dataUnavailable">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2 class="text-center rcm-bold-message">Server data is not available.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="noPermissions">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2 class="text-center rcm-bold-message">You do not have sufficient permissions.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mhhhhh, why do you want to do that? Services are meant to be `Singleton` so you don't want to use different instances in your application so there's no reason to test it like this. Btw, use `useClass` instead of `useValue` if you override services, since `useClass` will make sure that dependencies are resolved.

Comment: I want to do that to deliver another service method outcome to different test cases. Trying to test component behaviour in case user has read permissions (hasReadPermissions() { return true; }) and in case has not (hasReadPermissions() { return false; }). Is there better solution for that?

Comment: Ah okay, now i see it ;) Okay basically you test your component in this test, right? So you stub your service for it because the actual service doesn't matter in this test, but it still will be used. But that doesn't necessarily mean you have to use the return values of your stubbed service. For example if you have a `*ngIf` on your `h2` element which you are testing, and this `*ngIf* depends on the return value of your service method, just ignore that fact and mock the property which is used in your `*ngIf` directly. Hope i'm clear.

Comment: If you add the part of your component template you want to test to your question i could explain it better via an answer if you want.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Component under test added to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, as i said in my comment to your question, you basically can ignore the actual response of your service in a test of your component (because the outcome of your service methods, should be testet seperately anyway).

If you want to change the return value, so that you don't have to keep different stubs or instances of these stubs / services, you can use a `jasmine.Spy` to spy on this method and use the provided method `returnValue` to define the value which will be returned in your test:

```
let spy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(comp.userService, 'hasUserReadPermissions').and.returnValue(false);

let message = debugElement.query(By.css('h2'));
expect(message).toBe('you have no permissions');
```

---

Just a quick hint regarding your component: You're using a method in your `*ngIf`. That's okay, *most of the times*, but remember that this function will be called in every digest circle of angulars lifecycle hooks (meaning on `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterViewInit`, `ngDoCheck` and so on). This will result in your function being called multiple times in a second. Don't do that with methods that are somewhat "slow" (i know, slow is relative). Call the function once inside your component, keep a reference to the return value like you did with `dataUnavailable`.

Hope it helps.

---

### Update for completion:

*Sometimes*, you don't want to mock a method in a test despite it being called, but prevent a call to it with its actual implementation (maybe because it does stuff you don't care about in your test, or it has dependencies or thousands of nested observables or simple timeouts which are a mess to test then). In this case you can actually just override the function:

```
  comp.userService.hasUserReadPermissions = function() { return false; };
  // do some stuff so the function is called
  expect(...).toBe(...);
```

Seems ugly, but it does safe lives sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you provide to less information about how you set the user is it in your component or service?

After your inject you can use a spyOn and return your user.

spyOn(userService, 'getUser').and.returnValue(yourUser);

Comment: User is set and kept in service. Please note the code parts from edit.

Comment: Ahh oke see the above answer. 
I made the post before your edit.
Also note that the post above is saying false = false it is not really a test.
Try to add a user then the method of userService should automatic say hasUserReadPermissions = true or false.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me, hope it works for you also

```
 it('should render appropriate message when user has not read permissions', 
     inject([UserService, AnotherService], (userServiceStub: UserService, 
            anotherServiceStub: AnotherService ) => {
            let message = debugElement.query(By.css('h2'));
            expect(message).toBe('you have no permissions');
       }));
```

I just added another service separated by a comma.